# VC generalization bound example question

Tags: machine-learning, vc-dimension

I feel it's a really basic problem yet I can't wrap my head around it. The problem is Exercise 2.5 from Yaser S. Abu-Mostafa's book *Learning From Data*. We are given a learning model with growth function $m=N+1$ where $N$ is the number of data points, from this the VC dimension is automatically given as $d=1$. The question is now to "estimate the probability that $E_\text{out}$ will be within $0.1$ of $E_\text{in}$ given $100$ training examples." $E_\text{out}$ is the out-of-sample error and $E_\text{in}$ the in-sample error. I set $\epsilon=0.1$.

My thought is that from the VC generalization bound

$$E_{\text {out }} \leq E_{\text{in}} + \underbrace{\sqrt{\frac{8}{100} \ln \frac{4(2 \cdot 100+1)}{\delta}}}_{\epsilon}=E_{\text {in }}+0.1$$

I can solve for $\delta$ and get $709.528...$. This seems strange since the VC generalization bound is true with probability $1-\delta$, but this would be a negative number and not a valid probability.

Generally it's strange to even look at the plot of the VC generalization bound vs. $\delta$, since $\delta \notin [0,1]$.